# React, React-Router, access-token and session time out

Tags: session, reactjs, react-router, json-web-token

I have difficult to take the next step in my solution, and I would much appreciate any help. :)

The LoginForm component is used to authenticate and if success, an access-token will be returned and stored in localStorage.

I try to implement some kind of session time out function that will redirect the user to the LoginForm component if the access-tokens has run out of time. I have created an api endpoint for this and try to use it in the onEnter hook function for the protected routes.

The redirectToLogin function do a call to this endpoint and if error it should redirecto to the LoginForm. The LoginForm always check if the access token exist in local storage, if so, it "knows" a session time out has happened and can display a proper message.

The problem seems that the redirectToLogin function only executes when I navigate from the / route to a protected route and not when I navigate lets say between /users to /users/:id

I'm sure I do not unserstand the router properly and I really really would appreciate any help?

My routing logic looks like this.

```
let routes = { 
  // Base component render an AppBar component and if the access token 
  // is stored in localStorage, the Dasboard component will be rendered,
  // otherwise the Home component.
  Component: Base 
  childroutes: [  

    { path: '/',
      getComponent: (nextState, cb) => {

        // Dynamically load the correct component
        if (Client.hasAccessToken()) {
          cb(null, Dashboard)
        }
        else {
          cb(null, Home)
        }
      }
    },
    // Public routes
    { path: '/login',
      component: LoginForm
    },
    ...
    // Protected routes that requires authentication
    { onEnter: redirectToLogin,
      childRoutes: [
        { path: '/users',
          getComponent: (nextState, cb) => {
            cb(null, UserTable)
          }
        },
        { path: '/users/:id',
          getComponent: (nextState, cb) => {
            cb(null, UserEdit)
          }
        },
        ....
     ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: I took a cup of coffe and now I'm thinking that I do it completely wrong. It is up to all components in the protected area to handle time outs, the components that do any rest call to any api endpoints that requires the access token will get an error message if the time out has happen. Can anybody confirm my concerns about this? :-)

Comment: yeah, actually the client shouldn't worry about the token it has. The server will check the token anyway, right? So just respond with "Not Authorized" and if the client receives this message remove the Token form the localStorage and redirect to login.. The best would be to handle it somewhere central in the api module, then you only need to handle it once

Comment: Yes, thanks for your confirmation. Hovewer, if I remove the access token from localStorage before I redirect to the Login form, then the Login form does not know to display a message like "session time out". I guess it is down to your last sentence, handle it in the api module?

Comment: Are you using some kind of flux? Maybe redux? Then you could set it to the loginError for example which is then rendered in your form.

Comment: No, I have spend all my holiday to learn rect and react router and start to realize I should propable used redux or something like that as well. But, I see it as learning, now I start to see the limits what I can do or not. I solved this bu temporarily store a session time out message in the localStorage, in the Login component I check if it exist, if so a remove it. :-)

Comment: you can also store it as a global var in `window` like `window.loginError = "Error"`